# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when I destroy a few bodies LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

After destroying a few bodies I get this:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x71929823b800 in tid 13461 (GLThread 46), pid 13432 (com.mygdx.game)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A  Cmdline: com.mygdx.game
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A  pid: 13432, tid: 13461, name: GLThread 46  >>> com.mygdx.game <<<
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #00 pc 0000000000036958  /data/app/~~Kbde8VLpHehJDoH_wtbk9g==/com.mygdx.game-a7HrSt4SXhSXonRVircwDQ==/lib/x86_64/libgdx-box2d.so (b2BlockAllocator::Allocate(int)+72) (BuildId: 718b99a1c37cd23164f86ef804f0169668c31984)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #01 pc 000000000001b04d  /data/app/~~Kbde8VLpHehJDoH_wtbk9g==/com.mygdx.game-a7HrSt4SXhSXonRVircwDQ==/lib/x86_64/libgdx-box2d.so (b2World::CreateBody(b2BodyDef const*)+29) (BuildId: 718b99a1c37cd23164f86ef804f0169668c31984)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #02 pc 0000000000037580  /data/app/~~Kbde8VLpHehJDoH_wtbk9g==/com.mygdx.game-a7HrSt4SXhSXonRVircwDQ==/lib/x86_64/libgdx-box2d.so (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_jniCreateBody+160) (BuildId: 718b99a1c37cd23164f86ef804f0169668c31984)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #05 pc 000000000016ad5c  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.createBody+128)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #07 pc 000000000024981a  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Gunstuff.Stuff.Bullet.createCircleBody+46)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #09 pc 00000000002498fa  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Gunstuff.Stuff.Bullet.<init>+102)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #11 pc 0000000000249418  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Gunstuff.Guns.Ak.shoot+144)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #13 pc 000000000024951c  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Gunstuff.Guns.Ak.update+200)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #15 pc 000000000024a1e4  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Screens.GameScreen.gameUpdate+76)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #17 pc 000000000024a6ee  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.mygdx.game.Screens.GameScreen.render+50)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #19 pc 00000000000bf6f0  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render+20)
2023-06-01 14:38:19.069 13486-13486 DEBUG                   pid-13486                            A        #21 pc 00000000000df452  /data/data/com.mygdx.game/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex (com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame+454)
```

I have no idea what went wrong.

Gamescreen class where I render, make step:

```
public GameScreen(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        world.step(1 / 45f, 6, 2);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gameUpdate(delta);
        main.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(main.camera.combined);
        main.camera.position.set(player.body.getPosition().x * PPM, player.body.getPosition().y * PPM, 0);
        main.camera.update();

        //MAP RENDERING
        mapRenderer.setView(main.camera);
        mapRenderer.render();
        b2dr.render(world, new Matrix4(main.camera.combined).scl(PPM));
        Main.batch.setProjectionMatrix(main.camera.combined);
        Main.batch.begin();
        gameRender(Main.batch);
        Main.batch.end();



        //STAGE DRAW
        Main.stage.act(delta);
        Main.stage.draw();

        main.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        main.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size; i++) {
            main.shapeRenderer.circle(bullets.get(i).position.x, bullets.get(i).position.y, bullets.get(i).size);
        }
        main.shapeRenderer.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        main.camera.viewportWidth = width;
        main.camera.viewportHeight = height;
        main.camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        mapRenderer.dispose();
        main.dispose();
    }
    public void gameRender(SpriteBatch batch) {
        //PLAYER ROTATION
        if (joystickL.direction.angleDeg() != 0) angle = joystickL.direction.angleDeg();
        if (joystickR.direction.angleDeg() != 0) angle = joystickR.direction.angleDeg();
        player.img.setRotation(angle);

        ammo_view.update(player);


        //ENEMY ROTATION
        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size; i++) {
            enemies.get(i).img.setRotation(enemies.get(i).direction.angleDeg());
            enemies.get(i).draw(batch);
        }
        player.draw(batch);
    }

    private void sweepDeadBodies() {
        world.getBodies(bodiesToDestroy);
        Iterator<Body> i = bodiesToDestroy.iterator();
        Body node=i.next();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Body oBj=node;
            node=i.next(); String data = (String) oBj.getUserData();
            if(data!=null && data.equals("delete")){
                world.destroyBody(oBj);
            }
        }
    }

    public void gameUpdate(float delta) {

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sweepDeadBodies();
            }
        });

        player.update();
        player.setDirection(joystickL.direction);
        player.gun.update(joystickR);
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size; i++) {
            //enemies.get(i).player_detection(player);
            enemies.get(i).update();
            enemies.get(i).handgun.update(joystickR);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size; i++) {
            //bullets.get(i).direction.rotateDeg(bullets.get(i).direction.angleDeg() + (float)getRandomDoubleBetweenRange(-10, 10));
            bullets.get(i).update();
        }

        if (player.gun.isFire && player.gun.ammo > 0) {
            if (Rumble.getRumbleTimeLeft() > 0) {
                Rumble.tick(delta);
                main.camera.translate(Rumble.getPos());
            }
        }
    }
```

ContactListener:

```
    public Array<Body> bodiesToDestroy = new Array<Body>();

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();
        if(fa == null || fb == null) System.out.println("no fixture");
        if(fa.getBody() == null || fb.getBody() == null) System.out.println("no body");
        if(fa.getBody().getUserData() == null || fb.getBody().getUserData() == null) System.out.println("no data");
        hit_wall_bullet(fa, fb);
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();
        if(fa == null || fb == null) System.out.println("no fixture at the end");
        if(fa.getBody() == null || fb.getBody() == null) System.out.println("no body at the end");
    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold manifold) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse contactImpulse) {

    }
    private void hit_wall_bullet(Fixture a, Fixture b) {
        if ((a.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_WALL || b.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_WALL) && (a.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_BULLET || b.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_BULLET)) {
            //Body toRemove = a.getBody().getType() == BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody ? a.getBody() : b.getBody();
            //bodiesToDestroy.add(toRemove);
            if (a.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_BULLET) a.getBody().setUserData("delete");
            if (b.getFilterData().categoryBits == BIT_BULLET) b.getBody().setUserData("delete");

        }
    }
```

I would like to solve that rediculous error

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple contacts and this leads to you deleting the same object twice. Deleting the same object twice in box2D causes the native lib to crash because it uses pooling internally.

Fortunately You can check if your `bodiestodestroy` contains duplicates and if it does replace with a `Set`.

Comment: actually, your suggestion partly helped me: when the player(when I turn off enemies'es guns) shoots - no problems, but when enemies shoot the error still raises